# What is the origin of "sucker" and "it sucks"?

Tags: idioms

I think it is clear that a *sucker* means somebody who is naive or gullible, while *it sucks* means “it is bad”, but I wonder where these two terms come from and what they mean originally?

Could *sucker* actually mean a baby who was just born and therefore, naive and can’t tell if somebody is lying to them?  If so, then what about *it sucks*?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=suck) has for *suck*:

> O.E. sucan, from PIE root *sug-/suk-* of imitative origin. Meaning “do fellatio” is first recorded 1928. Slang sense of “be contemptible” first attested 1971 (the underlying notion is of fellatio).

and *sucker*:

> “young mammal before it is weaned”, late 14c., agent noun from *suck*. Slang meaning “person who is easily deceived” is first attested 1836, in American English, on notion of naivete; the verb in this sense is from 1939. But another theory traces the slang meaning to the fish called a *sucker* (1753), on the notion of being easy to catch in their annual migrations.

Comment: the word fellatio actually comes from the Latin verb fellare, which means to suck.

Answer (score 7):

Short for "cock sucker", which is the days of non-political correctness and rampant homophobia was a serious and widespread insult/put down. "You suck" having the "cock" understood.

Comment: You say that as if cocksucker is _not_ a serious insult/put down nowadays.

Comment: but... a girl can say "you suck" with a smile and all people feel happy... but if the third word is implied, I think people's reaction will be different

Answer (score 0):

In the pruning of fruit trees and the like, a "sucker" is a branch which forms in one season. They typically fail to produce fruit and so are trimmed off. I would suppose that it's possible this might be how an agricultural people would refer to someone who is too young and not likely to do anything useful.

For example see: 
http://www.gardeningknowhow.com/trees-shrubs/tree-sucker-removal-and-tree-sucker-control.htm